# How to reassign values to new rows and keep rest of values in these new rows

Tags: r

First of all I'm not sure if I titled this topic right but I hope description will clear everything.

Firstly, I had data frame like this

```
vehicle type                    number1 number2
"car"   "truck, SUV, hatchback" 2       3
"bike"  "scraper, lowrider"     5       7
"plane" "bomber"                2       3
```

Secondly, I've used great `cSplit`function from `splitstackshape` to change this data frame to something like this

```
vehicle type1     type2      type3       number1 number2
"car"   "truck"   "SUV"      "hatchback" 2       3
"bike"  "scraper" "lowrider" NA          5       7
"plane" "bomber"  NA         NA          2       3
```

But as my final result I would like to see something like this

```
vehicle type        number1 number2
"car"   "truck"     2       3
"car"   "SUV"       2       3
"car"   "hatchback" 2       3 
"bike"  "scraper"   5       7
"bike"  "lowrider"  5       7
"plane" "bomber"    2       3
```

And obviously I have no idea how to do this and I don't even know if topic describes my problem enough (I have feeling that package tidy may be helpful).
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `direction` is `wide` in `cSplit`.  We can specify the `direction='long'` to get the expected output.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, "type", sep=", ", "long")
#    vehicle      type number1 number2
#1:     car     truck       2       3
#2:     car       SUV       2       3
#3:     car hatchback       2       3
#4:    bike   scraper       5       7
#5:    bike  lowrider       5       7
#6:   plane    bomber       2       3
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you some much @arkun